# Consulta SQL con dos campos en PHP y MySQL

Tags: php, mysql-workbench

Tengo un pequeño problema por favor si alguien me puede ayudar =D,estaré muy agradecido.
al buscar productos para venta:
solo me jala para buscar un solo nombre o campo, quiero buscar por ejemplo 
"tablet asus" dos campos.

[image: esta es mi ventana de busqueda]

este es mi código:

```
public static function getLike($p){

$sql = "select * from product inner join category on product.category_id=category.id_categoria where name like '%$p%' or marca like '%$p%' or modelo like '%$p%' or barcode like '%$p%' or description like '%$p%'";

    $query = Executor::doit($sql);
        return Model::many($query[0],new ProductData());
    }
```

Comment: Creo que lo que deberías hacer es separar el string en "tablet" y "asus" y ya luego hacer tantas consultas como palabras tenga el string. No tengo claro si eso es a lo que te refieres

Comment: Como dice @HéctorE, tienes que crear dos valores y entonces lanzar la búsqueda. Puedes usar el espacio en blanco que haya entre los valores para separarlos y crear criterios de búsqueda con cada valor. También, necesitas darle seguridad a tu consulta actual. Ejecutar consultas pasándoles los datos directamente supone un grave riesgo de **inyección de código malicioso** que puede afectar a tu sistema.

Comment: Gracias!! =D, bueno, lo que pasa el código de sql  solo busca 1 variable por ejemplo pongo en el buscador "laptop" y solo me da solo laptop, lo que quiero es buscar 2 variables, osea que yo al poner en el buscador digamos por ejemplo"laptop hp" me busque dos variables.

Comment: @A.Cedano Gracias por la sugerencia, pero aun estoy en nivel pollito XD

Comment: De entrada, no me parece una buena idea como lo estás haciendo, aunque es posible. Yo usaría dos o tres cuadros de texto para filtrar por `nombre`, `marca` y `modelo`. De lo contrario, vas a tener que escribir unos `LIKE` interminables y que podrían ser costosos en el caso de una base de datos con varios millones de registro. No obstante si lo quieres hacer así, es posible. Pero tendrías que crear un array a partir del texto escrito dividiendo por el espacio en blanco y a partir de ahí crear los diferentes criterios de búsqueda... tomando en cuenta que podrían ser 1, 2, 3... o más

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al pasar las variables directamente en la consulta te expones a un ataque de [inyección SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL), deberías considerar utilizar [sentencias preparadas](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) que entre otras cosas ayudan a evitar eso.

Dicho esto puedes usar CONCAT para poder buscar en varios campos con un string de esta manera:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM product INNER JOIN category ON product.category_id=category.id_categoria WHERE CONCAT (name, marca, modelo, barcode, description) LIKE '%$p%';
```

En tu caso puedes usar la función [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php) para obtener todas las palabras de tu query y luego ir concatenandolas en la busqueda de esta manera

```
public static function getLike($p){
    $params = explode(' ', $p);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM product INNER JOIN category ON product.category_id=category.id_categoria WHERE ";
    foreach ($params as $index => $param) {
        if ($index === 0) {
            $sql .= "CONCAT (name, marca, modelo, barcode, description) LIKE '%$param%' ";
        } else {
            $sql .= "OR CONCAT (name, marca, modelo, barcode, description) LIKE '%$param%' ";
        }
    }
    $sql .= ";";

    $query = Executor::doit($sql);
    return Model::many($query[0],new ProductData());
}
```

Comment: gracias =D,@kacospro

Comment: ¿Si te sirvió la respuesta? @AllegroCantabile

Comment: Si @kacospro, gracias solo se tenia que cambiar el OR por AND, pero lo que si me entro duda es el comentario de Hector E, que pueden entrar ami bd.

Comment: Genial @AllegroCantabile!! Si resolvió tu problema puedes marcar como respuesta correcta. Y si, tienes un gran riesgo de sufrir un ataque de [inyección SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL), [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%c3%b3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%c3%b3n-sql-en-php) hay mas información de como podrías evitarla